# Player update vs world update module in game development

Tags: game-development

I am new to game development and have encountered the term "player update module" while reading through my game development textbook but I cannot find more details about what they mean.

The textbook states that Player Update Module is "The section of code that adjusts the current state of a player's object to account for any interactions with the game environment or opponents."

Does module always mean "a section of code"? Does it have something to do with this section of code being modular?
Does a player's object mean an item that the player is holding or in his inventory?
Does current state mean whether the object is active or in play?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome new user. I would honestly throw that book out. It sounds like total nonsense.  Two things (1) there's actually a "game dev" stack overflow https://gamedev.stackexchange.com your question would do much better there.  (2) Are you using Unity3D?  If not, you should start using it. (It's totally free unless you are a big business. Realistically it's the only way to learn game development. Scenes, models, game physics.  Enjoy